# How can I extract info from xml page with R

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I'm trying to get all the info from this page: http://ws.parlament.ch/affairs/19110758/?format=xml

First I download the file into `file`and parse it then with `xmlParse(file)`.

```
download.file(url = paste0(http://ws.parlament.ch/affairs/19110758/?format=xml), destfile = destfile)
file <- xmlParse(destfile[])
```

I now want to extract all the information I need. For example the title and the ID-number. I tried something like this:

```
title <- xpathSApply(file, "//h2", xmlValue)
```

But this gives me only an error: `unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature ‘"XMLDocument"`

Next thing I tried is this:

```
library(plyr)

test <-ldply(xmlToList(file), function(x) { data.frame(x[!names(x)=="id"]) } )
```

This gives me a `data.frame`with some Info. But I lose info such as `id` (which is most important).

I'd like to get a `data.frame` with a row (only one row per affair) containing all the Information of one affair, such as ``` id``updated ``` ``` additionalIndexing``affairType ```etc.

With this, it works (example for `id`):

```
infofile <- xmlRoot(file)

nodes <-  getNodeSet(file, "//affair/id")
id <-as.numeric(lapply(nodes, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you to your XML:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(httr)

srcXML <- getURL("http://ws.parlament.ch/affairs/19110758/?format=xml", 
            .opts=c(user_agent("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"),
              verbose()))

myXMLFile <- xmlTreeParse(substr(srcXML,4,nchar(srcXML)))
```

I would have used just `GET()` from `httr` but it doesn't seem to pass the `user-agent` along well (I need to test it when I'm not behind a proxy to be sure of what the specific error is). I also did the `substr()` as there's a bunch of weird characters at the front that cause the `xmlTreeParse()` call to error out.

Comment: Thank you. That works on my screen. But how can I download the file keeping all the information html would loose?

Comment: `writeLines(substr(srcXML,4,nchar(srcXML)), "filenametowriteto.xml")` should work

Comment: Perfect. I now got the first part of my task (I'm obviously very unable to master). Now, the data-extraction does still not work: `id  <- xpathSApply(myXMLFile, "//name[1]", xmlValue)`gives me: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature ‘"XMLDocument"’`

Comment: can you elaborate (in your original q above) what info you wld like to extract? It might not be difficult for me or others to provide a more optimal way to get what you need out of the XML docs.

Answer (score 4):

It is an HTML file, not an XML file. You need to use `htmlParse`:

```
destfile <- tempfile() # make this example copy-pasteable
download.file(url = "http://ws.parlament.ch/affairs/19110758/?format=xml", destfile = destfile)
file <- htmlParse(destfile)
title <- xpathSApply(file, '//h2')
xmlValue(title[[1]])
# [1] "Heilmittelwesen. Gesetzgebung"
```

Comment: But if I htmlParse the document, much of the information is lost. See: http://ws.parlament.ch/affairs/19110758/?format=xml I need to extract most of the info... therefore I need to xmlParse the document. Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: You're right, it seems using R's `download.file` function coerces the server to send you HTML instead of XML, probably due to HTTP header reasons. Try downloading the file manually and using `xmlParse`.

Comment: I can't do this for 30000 documents manually :-) What am I doing  wrong with the extraction? `test <- xpathSApply(file, "//h2", xmlValue)` gives me therefore an empty vector.

Comment: No, take a look at `readLines(destfile)`, it is clearly an HTML file. The problem is with the request. Try using a [batch downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloadall/ajffocjdcmpgjmdfdfkdfdbkjafbkcke?hl=en), I believe their server will not serve you XML unless you mimic a browser well enough (I am not sure of the exact headers).

Comment: ok... With chrome I can see the xml file, with firefox, this is somehow not possible. I'll dive into the thing, but as you may have noticed, I'm pretty new, so if anyone knows how i can force R to download this correctly I'd be grateful.