# Follow up: How to download xml, when it somehow is html

Tags: xml, r, rcurl

This is a follow up to a question I posed a year ago here: [How can I extract info from xml page with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717412/how-can-i-extract-info-from-xml-page-with-r)

The solution suggested worked for quite some time. Unfortunately, I never gave it some thought after it worked smoothly. Now R throws an error at me and I obviously I don't know how to proceed.

Here's what I want to do:

```
require(XML)
require(RCurl)

url <- "http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?affairNumberFilter=20130051&format=xml"
affairs_det <- getURL(url, .opts=c(user_agent("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"), 
                            verbose()), asNames=TRUE)  
#This worked, but not anymore
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : No URL set!
In addition: Warning message:
In mapCurlOptNames(names(.els), asNames = TRUE) :
Unrecognized CURL options: output, auth_token, options, fields, headers, method, url

affairs_det_parsed <- xmlTreeParse(substr(affairs_det,4,nchar(affairs_det)), encoding = "UTF-8")
```

The question is somehow twofold. First, how should I download the file which seems to be xml, but if I download it with `download.file(url, destfile="test.xml")` it appears to be html? I believe the setting of `user_agent` handled that...?

Second, I don't understand the error?

**Edit**

I'd like to access the information via the tag, here for example `id`. Before the mysterios error, this worked as well.

```
infofile <- xmlRoot(affairs_det_parsed)

#gets councillor ids
id <- getNodeSet(infofile, paste0("//councillors/councillor/id"))
id <- lapply(id, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
id <- sapply(id, "[[", 1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The following works for me. `affairs_det <- getURL(url, asNames=TRUE);`, though throws the warning you mentioned. Infact even `download.file(url,"test.xml")` works fine. And the downloaded `xml` gets parsed fine. Not sure if the same parsed `xml` serves your purpose.

Comment: @Frash This does download the content, but unfortunately without the tags.

Comment: "Appears to be XML.." It is not. http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?affairNumberFilter=20130051&format=xml results in XML not HTML. Load it into your browser, then view page source.

Comment: But then in R, it is HTML. Even when your request was explicitly format=XML. Odd. If you can get this into R as XML, you'd be better off. Sometimes HTML can be finicky to parse. I ran the page through https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fws.parlament.ch%2Fvotes%2Fcouncillors%3FaffairNumberFilter%3D20130051&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 and received warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original answer mixed RCurl and httr syntax, which is weird. Your snippet above neglected to indicate use of httr. Likely httr has changed but continues to work with itself, but did not think that it would be used with RCurl.

```
library(httr)
x = GET(url)
```

retrieves the file.

```
stop_for_status(x)
```

checks that there were no errors.

```
xml = content(x)
```

gets the XML content. Alternatively, download to disk and use XML to parse it

```
t <- tempfile()
GET(url, write_disk(t))
xml = xmlParse(t)
```

Comment: I'd also recommend switching to the xml2 package which doesn't leak memory and can load directly from an httr connection.

Answer (score 0):

Well I almost got true XML into R rather than HTML. I think that would be helpful.

The parsing will be more reliable with XML rather than HTML (also keep in mind your source is serving HTML with errors in it) The XML file is simple, so writing xpath's will be much easier.

I first used command line curl, because I'm more familiar with it. This command line pulled in XML:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/xml"\
     -H "Content-Type: application/xml"\
     -X GET http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?affairNumberFilter=20130051&format=xml
```

I translated that to this Rcurl that tests for URI existence, and then loads it into doc:

```
if(url.exists("http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?affairNumberFilter=20130051&format=xml")) 
{
    curl = getCurlHandle()
    curlSetOpt( .opts = list(httpheader = c(Accept ="application/xml", "Content-Type"="application/xml"), verbose = TRUE),curl = curl)
    doc = getURL("http://ws.parlament.ch/votes/councillors?affairNumberFilter=20130051&format=xml", curl = curl)
}
```

But `xmlParse` throws an error saying saying `Error: XML content does not seem to be XML`. Visual inspection of the downloaded file reveals leading trash characters, specifically `"ï»¿`. I think that needs to be addressed before further processing.

It's interesting because command line Curl didn't have those stray leading characters.

Maybe someone with more experience could take this further.